# how to convert a for loop callback into sync in node js (Express js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, asynchronous

I have an array of a collection object_id be like [123, 426, 789]
I need to write a for loop to find that object from the collection to some operation for every object, currently, I am coding like

```
let obj = ["5acf60d327cca60880b4a257", "5a9e3c642b6b04387208b24c", "5acf60ab27cca60880b4a252"];
for(let i =0; i<=obj.lenth;i++){
    if(i=== obj.length){
        return callback({
            code : 200,
            status: 'sucess',
            message: "Mail Requested Sucessfully"
        });
    }else{
        user.findbyId(obj[i]).exec((err, userData) => {
            if(err){
                console.log("user not found");
            }else{
                transporter.sendMail({
                    from: '"Fred Foo " <foo@example.com>', // sender address
                    to: userData.emailID, // list of receivers
                    subject: 'Hello ✔', // Subject line
                    html: '<b>Hello world?</b>' // html body
                }, (error, info) => {
                    if (error) {
                        onsole.log('Message sent: %s', error);
                    }
                    console.log('Message sent:', info);
                });
            }
        })
    }
}
```

currently, it's working as asynchronous, it there any good approach to make it in a synchronous way

Comment: `onsole.log('Message sent: %s', error);` should be `console.log('Message sent: %s', error);` (just on a side-note)

Comment: even better: keep your request asynchronous, but ordered. For example with not launching all requests at once, but rather make it so that the result callback of first request fires the second, etc.

Comment: That's a weird looking code :)

You are basically looping over objects and creating multiple async calls and at the end of the loop (which is triggered by i === obj.length) you are calling the callback...

Why not call the callback right after your "standard" loop that iterates until < obj.length?

Also your errors get lost. this is not a good practice.

What do you mean by synchronous way? I think you mean you want to wait until the emails are sent? (but asynchronously) if yes, then use async.parallel which will call the callback once emails are sent. (promise.all for promises)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Make your callback to return a promise and then you can `await` in for loop for that to be resolved and rest of the loop code will be executed after the callback has been resolved.

This is the way to go

```
(async function(){
 for(let i =0; i<=obj.lenth;i++){
   if(i=== obj.length){
      await callback1(params)
   }else{
      await callback2(params)
   }
})();
```

Define your `user.findbyId(obj[i]).exec((err, userData)` in some promise

Something like

```
function callback2(params){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
      user.findbyId(obj[i]).exec((err, userData) => {
        if(err){
            resolve (error)
        }else{ /*send message and resolve promise*/
 })
}
```

Comment: `.exec()` already returns a `Promise`: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-exec

Comment: it's probably easier for the OP to implement in his code, but one has to keep in mind that the effect is similar to a synchronous behaviour. The javascript engine will actually be stuck in the for loop as long as requests are not complete, with possible side-effects to the user interaction with UI